# How I can make switch case check all cases

Tags: php, switch-statement

What if I want to make each case in the switch case been a equlity condition like this code example

```
switch (true){
   case X==Y:
    //do something 
   case X==Z:
    //do something 
   case X has 0 :
    //do something 
}
```

Its working well if I want to check only one condition,By adding break
 ,But what if i want to check all cases and do only true cases

Comment: use `if/else` .

Comment: switch isn't the right choice for your task

Comment: I know but i tried to make some thing simpler

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change flavor from `if.....else` and want to use `switch....case`

So you can try like this

```
$test = true;
$x=1;$y=1;$z=2;//uncomment any one and check
//$x=1;$y=2;$z=1;//uncomment any one and check
//$x=0;$y=1;$z=1;//uncomment any one and check
switch ($test){
   case $x==$y:
        echo "x==y";
        break;
   case $x==$z:
        echo "x==z";
        break;
   case $x==0 :
        echo "x has 0";
        break;
   default:
        echo "he!he!he!he!he!he!";
}
```

uncomment any one and check all conditions

Check demo here : https://eval.in/907483

Here using `$test = true;` means if your condition goes true in `case` inside `switch`

Comment: https://3v4l.org/iQiM3